# Selenium webdriver driver.get(url) hangs... sometimes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS as a webdriver to load some urls. Usually, the program runs fine. However, it hangs on `driver.get(url)` a lot, and i'm wondering if there is anything I can do about it?

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= path_to_phantomjs_exe, service_log_path= path_to_ghostdriver_log)
driver.get(url)
```

It will just hang trying to load a certain url forever. But if i try it again, it might work. Are webdrivers/phantomJS really just that unstable? I guess last resort would be to constantly call `driver.get(url)` until it finally loads, but is that really going to be necessary? Thanks!

**EDIT:** It seems to only hang when loading the first link out of a list of them. It eventually does load, however, but after a few minutes. The rest of the links load within seconds. Any help at all would be great.

Comment: Did you try using Chrome or Firefox, and did you get the same issue?

Comment: Yes, and the pages load almost instantly, so it is not an issue of a long loading page. PhantomJS just seems to have a hard time i guess... any ideas on how to diagnose/debug/fix?

Comment: I assume you have the latest phantomjs and you have tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It did not use to do this. Everything always ran smoothly, now all of a sudden it takes minutes to load the first url. Everytime I interrupt it, the last call is 
`data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)`, which im guessing is what it's hanging on. Don't know if that helps.

**edit:** Also, it works fine on my mac, which is on the same connection.

Comment: I have similar problems (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108260/geb-selenium-tests-hang-loading-new-page) - what do you see if you pass the "--debug=true" option to the phantomjs command line?

Comment: @wrschneider99 The problem actually just... went away. And I have no way of recreating it. It had only hung sometimes... and other times it worked fine. There really was no explanation to it from my perspective, so I wish the best of luck to you.

Answer (score 10):

I've answered this exact problem on this post here: [Geb/Selenium tests hang loading new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108260/geb-selenium-tests-hang-loading-new-page/40198823#40198823) but copied it here because I see that this question is older.

I hope you can find a way to implement this into your code, but this is what worked for me when I was having a similar situation with PhantomJS hanging.

I traced it to be hanging on a `driver.get()` call, which for me was saying something wasn't going through or the webdriver just wasn't - for some reason - giving the load successful command back to the driver, allowing the script to continue.

So, I added the following:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

# set timeout information
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
```

I've tested this at a time of 5 (seconds) and it just didn't wait long enough and nothing would happen. 15 seconds worked great for me, but that's maybe something you should test.

On top of this, I also created a loop whenever there was an option for the webdriver to timeout, so that the `driver.get()` could attempt to re-send the `.get()` command. Implementing a try / except stacked scenario, I was able to approach this:

```
while finished == 0:
    try:
        driver.get(url3)
        finished = 1
    except:
        sleep(5)
```

I have seen an except handle as:

```
except TimeoutException as e:
    #Handle your exception here
    print(e)
```

but I had no use for this. It might be nice to know how to catch specific exceptions, though.

See this solution for more options for a timeout: Setting timeout on selenium webdriver.PhantomJS

Answer (score 3):

So I was having the same problem:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= path_to_phantomjs_exe, service_log_path= path_to_ghostdriver_log)
driver.get(url)
```

So I changed the service_log_path to:

```
service_log_path=os.path.devnull
```

This seemed to work for me!!!