# how can I use PhantomJS with a different version of GhostDriver?

Tags: phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am struggling with a PhantomJS/GhostDriver issue in my CI builds.  ([Geb/Selenium tests hang loading new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108260/geb-selenium-tests-hang-loading-new-page))

Unfortunately there is no PhantomJS 2.0 binary for Linux yet, and I have not successfully been able to build it from source.

In the meantime, is there a way I can run the latest GhostDriver from within an older version of PhantomJS?

Comment: Interesing, but probably not since it is directly included in PhantomJS. You may experiment with running GhostDriver directly in the 1.x version since it is simply JavaScript. Early versions of PhantomJS didn't include GhostDriver so they too needed to be run somehow.

Comment: Looks like it's breaking for me.  In theory you can do it -- you can just run ghostdriver/src/main.js as the phantomjs argument, or use the Java binding property phantomjs.ghostdriver.path ; but it breaks because of the `cookiejar` module which may be provided by PhantomJS itself, and is not compatible across versions

Comment: more precisely- cookiejar is a builtin PhantomJS module (like webpage) so this dependency is not consistent across versions